# How can I pause an execution without using Thread.Sleep()

Tags: c#, winforms, wait

I've got a few lines of codes for example:

```
MessageBox.Show("1");

Sleep(1000);

MessageBox.Show("2");

Sleep(1000);

MessageBox.Show("3");
```

And I want to make a pause of 1 second before continuing to the next code line without using `Thread.Sleep`; because it freezes the whole Form and terminates the lines of codes that was supposed to be executed before the sleep code. I don't use message boxes for this, I used just for an example I know it would of work with those.

With the lines I originally use it doesn't work. Is there any other alternative to wait for 1s before continuing running the codes? Thanks.

Comment: yes make your method async and use `await Task.Delay(1000)`

Comment: *"Is there any other alternative"* - many. `async/await` is probably the best. If you can split operation into steps then `Timer` can do. If you want to avoid UI freezing, then look into multithreading: `Task`, `Thread`, `BackgroundWorker`, etc.

Comment: you should provide more information. Please post the signature of your method and tell us which UI technology you are using. WPF, WinForms ect...

Answer (score 3):

yes make your method async and use await Task.Delay(1000)

```
public async Task MyAsyncMethod()
{
    //Action 1  
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    //Action 2  
    await Task.Delay(1000);


    //Action 3  
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

EDIT:

If using Winforms this async pattern has to go to the highes method in the hierarchy. So let's say you really have a button click event in which you want to call this method. Then you have to make the click method async!

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("STUFF Before");
    await MyAsyncMethod();
    Console.WriteLine("STUFF @ the END");
}

public async Task MyAsyncMethod()
{
    //Action 1  
    Console.WriteLine("Action 1 ");
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    //Action 2  
    Console.WriteLine("Action 2 ");
    await Task.Delay(1000);


    //Action 3  
    Console.WriteLine("Action 3 ");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

To realize this, you need to declare the return type of the `MyAsyncMethod` as `Task`:

```
public async Task MyAsyncMethod()    
               ^
               !
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be done in the Dispatcher?

Comment: It's not working for me. I'm creating this method then calling it when I want to wait 3 seconds. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @GucciHoodie - maybe but it is hard to tell if you do not post the code that you are now running. Update your question with the new code you are using.

Comment: @GucciHoodie please post your method as I already mentioned in the comment above

Comment: @GucciHoodie I made an example how this can be used in Winforms to work

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

After the comments made in the response, the best solution is to use `await Task.Delay(time);`

```
private async void AsyncMethod()
{
    //do what you want here
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

---

This way is a bad practice like @MickyD said in his comment:

> It causes your GUI application to become re-entrant. It is a throw-back to Visual Basic 6 and bad coding practices.

```
int seconds = 2;
if (seconds < 1) return;
DateTime _desired = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds);
while (DateTime.Now < _desired)
{
   System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
   //do whatever you want in this 2 seconds
}
```

Comment: Dude, Thank you so much!
I was searching for hours and nothing worked and I haven't seen any alternative code.
I pasted your code into a method and made a var inside the () so everytime I wanna pause I just use waitSec(4); and it waits the amount of seconds inside the ();
Awesome!

Comment: _**Never never never never never never never**_ use `Application.DoEvents`!.  It causes your GUI application to become re-entrant.  It is a throw-back to Visual Basic 6 and bad coding practices.  **Mong's** [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56056604/585968) is the way to go

Comment: @MickyD What's the main difference between Application.DoEvents and Async Task.Delay?

Comment: @Mikev -  [Use of Application.DoEvents()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5181777/1260204)

Comment: `Application.DoEvents()` has it's own Windows message pump processing and will process things like mouse clicks and keyboard.  The problem is, most of the time you are already in an event handler when you decided to call `DoEvents()` **but** you haven't returned yet from the event handler.  Now there is the possibility of processing another event from a menu/toolbar before the first has finished.  It will lead to unexpected application state.   The effect is similar to if you applied multithreading to code which isn't thread-safe